Chi-squared test of independence
Consider a contingency table which contains observation counts that are poisson distributed. In particular, $O_{ij}$ is $Poi(\lambda_{ij})$. If we apply CLT assuming $\lambda$ is large, then we get that $\frac{O_{ij}-\lambda_{ij}}{\sqrt{\lambda_{ij}}}$ is approximately the standard normal distribution.
Now, when carrying out a chi-squared test of independence, we use an approximate value for $\lambda_{ij}$ which is derived from the sample under the assumption of independence i.e. $E_{ij}$ when constructing the test statistic. Why would replacing the actual mean with the estimated one still work though? Moreover, would this test statistic become better both when I increase the total observations $(N)$ and when I increase the value of $\lambda_{ij}$?
Feel free to correct me on anything I mentioned. Been learning this stuff on my own, so I don't completely get it yet.


Why would replacing the actual mean with the estimated one still work though?

With the Poisson, in large samples (as $\lambda$ increases) it works pretty well.
For proof of asymptotic normality you might consider if you can use Slutsky to argue that it's still asymptotically normal.
However if you're using marginal totals in the contingency table to estimate parameters under $H_0$, you're no longer in a pure Poisson. Consider the simplest case of a 1D set of counts. Given the marginal total the counts are dependent (they add to the given margin) and conditionally you're now dealing with a multinomial set of counts. That complicates things slightly compared to the original Poisson (in terms of the normal approximation, you now have a degenerate multivariate normal approximation for the distribution of the counts for example). There's a similar issue with a 2D contingency table, but it's slightly more complicated.
I'd suggest dealing with the usual goodness of fit test first, where you can encounter a lot of the issues here in a simpler setting before jumping to the two way table.

Moreover, would this test statistic become better both when I increase the total observations (N) and when I increase the value of λij?


It's not clear to me how you're distinguishing $\lambda_{i,j}$ increasing separately from $N$. You'll need to clarify what you have in mind there.

It's not clear in what sense you mean better. Do you mean "more power" or do you mean "the chi-squared approximation is improved"? Or perhaps something else?



Hey, thanks for the answer. Regarding 1, my initial thought process was that increasing N (the sum of column/row totals) was possible without increasing the expected counts for each observation. The expected count might increase, decrease or stay the same upon increasing N depending on how the product of row i's and column j's total scales with N.
Regarding 2, I am mainly looking at whether the chi-square approximation can be improved.

Clearly it's possible for some $\lambda$'s (or their estimates) to go down while others go up by even more.  For properties of tests you'd normally be looking at parameter values, though presumably you're conditioning on the margins here and then having some sequence of them. I think the circumstances would need to be clarified. Are you holding the marginal totals ratio's constant?

No, I'm not holding the marginal totals ratio's constant as I increase N. The reason I thought increasing N would improve the approximation is because a higher N might provide a better approximation of the expected counts but I'm not sure if this improvement would be counteracted by a potential decrease in $\lambda_{ij}$.

I'm really not clear enough on what the circumstances are to say anything useful about it
